# A bet with numbers between 1 and 24

Tags: number-theory

An urn contains 24 balls numbered 1 to 24. Three balls are removed from the urn. If you have to place a simultaneous bet for both the sum (S) and product (P) of those three numbers, what numbers would you choose as S and P?
In general, what numbers would you choose for S and P if the urn contains not 24, but N balls numbered 1 to N?

Comment: This isn't really a puzzle, more mathematics and combinatorics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to maximize the number of ways to get sum $S$ and product $P$. A straightforward computer program indicates that for $N=24$ we do best to take

> $S=19$ and $P=144$, yielding 2 sets of 3 balls with that sum and product, namely {2,8,9} and {3,4,12}. (There are other choices of $(S,P)$ yielding the same number of sets; my program just shows one optimal configuration.)

Brute force by computer doesn't indicate to me any neat general solution for arbitrary $N$, nor would I particularly expect there to be one. When $N=25$ (i.e., 1 more than in the puzzle)

> we get three ways to get $(S,P)$ for the first time.

The next

> increase is at $N=72$.